# HtmlHelper NameFor method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, razor

Is there an `Html.NameFor` feature, that gets the `name` html attribute for a model item?

I'd like to use the following code in my Razor view:

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.User.Email" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.User.Email)">
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you - what HTML are you hoping to render?

Comment: The point in a HTML helper is to render HTML. All the above question is rendering will be plain text - use `name="@Model.User.Email"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the form name for a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327215/how-to-get-the-form-name-for-a-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is [`Html.NameFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method in the ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly.

Answer (score 12):

[`Html.NameFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is now included in MVC 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the value for a `name` attribute that will work when binding the input back to your model you could use the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` method. However invoking it would involve some code gymnastics.

How about just using the `TextBoxFor` helper?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.User.Email)
```