# How to get the form name for a property

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

In Razor I know that if you write

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PropertyX.PropertyY)
```

it will generate HTML like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PropertyX.PropertyY" value="...">
```

And (especially) if this was in an Editor Template it might generate this HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ParentProperty[12].PropertyX.PropertyY" value="...">
```

How do I get a name for an arbitrary property? I'm assuming there must be some way to do this using MVC infrastructure (perhaps some method or class?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a custom helper for that:

```
public static class NameExtensions
{
    public static string NameFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    )
    {
        var partialName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        return html
            .ViewContext
            .ViewData
            .TemplateInfo
            // You could do the same with GetFullHtmlFieldId
            // if you were interested in the id of the element
            .GetFullHtmlFieldName(partialName);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.NameFor(x => x.PropertyX.PropertyY)
```

Comment: It doesn't exactly follow the law of Demeter, but it gets me out of a bind. Thanks!

Comment: This is now implmented in MVC 4 [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444021/htmlhelper-namefor-method)  and a [MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703(v=vs.108).aspx)