# Binding select lists to a model in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, selectlist

Looking for some help with binding a select list to the model on form submit. This all works

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LectureRoomId, new SelectList(Model.LectureRooms, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "input-small chosen-select"})
```

However we are using chosen.js and want to use optgroup to group the drop down items. From what I understand optgroup isn't supported until mvc 4 or 5 in DropDownListFor so I have to right a custom select

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="venues" >
  @foreach (var group in Model.Campuses.Distinct())
  {
    <optgroup label="@group.Name">
    @foreach (var item in Model.LectureRooms.Where(r => r.CampusId == group.Id))
    {
      <option value="@item.Id" width="120px">@item.Name</option>
    }
    </optgroup>
  }
</select>
```

This code works in the sense that the list is populated and the groups all show correctly. However when submitting the form I don't know what the model object the list is binding its selected items to if any. Could you please assist in explaining how I would bind the selected items list to the model so I can use it in my controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your select doesn't have the name attribute so it doesn't get submitted. Change the line to:

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="venues" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.LectureRoomId)">
```

However the `NameFor` helper is available only in MVC 4, but you can implement your own helper as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7329380/1199711).